# Cannot send variables to a view

Tags: php, zend-framework

In my controller, i try to save a variable in session before sending it to a view:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['prenom'] = $form['prenom'];

$this->_view->prenom = $_SESSION['prenom'];

$this->_redirect('inscription');
```

then in my view i need to display it :

```
<div><input type="text" name="prenom" value="<?php if (isset($prenom)){echo $prenom;}?>" title="Pr&#233;nom *" class="small"/>
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

for starters let's be consistent and use Zend Framework.

```
//session_start();
//$_SESSION['prenom'] = $form['prenom'];  BECOMES
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('name'); //will automatically call session_start if required
$session->prenom = $form->getValue('prenom');//assumes $form is a valid Zend_Form object

//$this->_view->prenom = $_SESSION['prenom']; BECOMES
$this->view->prenom = $session->prenom; //$this->_view isn't a thing as far as I know
//if you are expecting the view variable to work after redirect... it won't
//$this->_redirect('inscription'); MAY BECOME
$this_forward('inscription');//will call new action without resetting the request
```

now for the view script:

```
//assumes you are in the correct view script
//when accessing variables passed to the view, use $this
<input type="text" name="prenom" value="<?php 
if (isset($this->prenom) { 
    echo $this->prenom;
}
?> " title="Prenom *" class="small"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The redirect method reset the set variables. You have to change your view instead. Something like:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('action-name-here');
```

Note: don't use native session method if you're using Zend Framework, use `Zend_Session`.

Answer (score 0):

`<div><input type="text" name="prenom" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['prenom'])) { echo $_SESSION['prenom']; }?>" title="Pr&#233;nom *" class="small"/>`

Answer (score 0):

When you use redirect method,Actual HTTP Redirection take place(page reload) thus all your variables will be reset.I think you are looking for forward method